Configuring VSFTPD more specificly
I'm new to Raspberry Pi and Linux in general.  I'm trying to setup my Pi4 as an FTP server.  VSFTPD seems to be the most prevalent option.  I have found many how-to's on it, but what is demonstrated always seems to be a configuration for each user to have R/W access on their own isolated folder.  I need to create several users (some with Read/Write and some with read-only access) and they need to see a common folder specifically for FTP sharing; a folder that all of the FTP users see by default when they log in. Can anyone tell me how to setup the config file to accomplish that?

Raspberry Pi OS already has sftp - all you have to do is login. There is no point in using a different client, they are similar. If you want a shared directory just create one and set appropriate permissions for your users e.g. by creating a group.

You can check this out: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-raspberry-pi/

All the vsftpd tutorials setup the users with their home directory shared.  I need each user to be able to see a central FTP folder that is not any of their home folder (in this case an external USB hard drive).  Also, how do I set some users to have read/write and others to have Read Only access?
